# iPad Password Lock for own app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipad

Anyone an idea how to show the user a keylock. I want the app to be locked after going to the home screen. When the user launches the app, he needs to fill in a code to unlock it. So what I need is something like this (dropbox example):

[image]

Anyone an idea how to do this? Any examples available or tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a View where you put buttons on it with several numbers.
Every time the user press on a button fill the password field, and then after the user typed the last one check if the password is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a full-screen-sized view in IB.  Add UITextFields for each of the inputs, and check the "secure" box.   In your appDelegate, add this view to the main Window.  If/when the user supplies the correct credentials - remove that view from it's superview and show your main app.  Send a becomeFirstResponder message to the first input field - this will display the keyboard.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get it in a view like this? Is it some kind of popover?

Comment: In IB, create a UIView that occupies the entire screen (mode=scale to fill), give it a blue background.  Create another smaller view with a title of Enter Passcode.  Create 4 UITextFields and place them inside the Enter Passcode view.  I don't think there is an out-of-the-box view that does this; you have to build it yourself.